# How can I get page numbers to link to the table of contents in latex?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, page-numbering

Just gonna ask a question from 4 years ago:

"I've seen a pdf LaTeX document where the page numbers at the bottom of the page are hyperref links, and clicking them causes you to jump to the contents table. I don't have the tex file and couldn't work out how it's done from the hyperref package. Can anyone help?"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393606/how-can-i-get-page-numbers-to-link-to-the-table-of-contents-in-latex

Exactly this is the thing I want. Unfortunely non of those answers work. 
Of course I could put a "\hyperref" at every page, but if I have a 100 site essay, that will take quite a long time.

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,colorlinks]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty} 
\setcounter{page}{0} 
\newpage
\section{Text 1}
\lipsum{1}
\newpage
\section{Text 2}
\lipsum{2}
\end{document}
```

Hopefully I didn´t deleted something related. 
Set

```
%\thispagestyle{empty} 
%\setcounter{page}{0}
```

To be able to see the first page number on the first page.

Comment: Did you try `\rfoot{\hyperref[TOC]{\thepage}}` ? Assuming you're using the `fancyhdr` package.

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing why the link answers don't work.

Comment: Doesn't my answer work for you?

Comment: The solution you wrote (karlkoeller) unfortunately only works for the first site. 
"minimal working example" added.

Comment: The solution \rfoot{\hyperref[TOC]{\thepage}} does compile, but does nothing with my dokumetn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,colorlinks]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@plain}{\thepage}{\hyperlink{contents}{\thepage}}{}{}
\makeatother
\addto\captionsgerman{\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{\hypertarget{contents}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\newpage
\section{Text 1}
\lipsum
\newpage
\section{Text 2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution only works for the first site.

Comment: @DracoLestrang Edited according to your MWE.

Comment: uhhh so what if I'm not using German?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```latex
% Make the page number link back to the table of contents
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\hyperlink{toc}{\thepage}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\hyperlink{toc}{\thepage}}
}
...

\hypertarget{toc}{} % anchor for page number to link to
\tableofcontents
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393606/how-can-i-get-page-numbers-to-link-to-the-table-of-contents-in-latex